# Spring data neo4j and spring version, conflicts

Tags: java, spring, maven, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I have spring services which works with spring data neo4j, I decided update spring data neo4j from 2.2 to current release - 3.1.4.RELEASE .
So the first I updated neo4j and project goes to fail, I updated Spring version, and with different versions different exceptions.
This services included in my front end and I am call it is from web.
So I do not know what is optimal configuration???
Configuration with maven.
Here is a pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2.GA</version>
        </dependency>
<!--        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.springframework.transaction</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1.RELEASE</version>
          <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>org.springframework.aop</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>org.springframework.beans</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>org.springframework.context</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>org.springframework.core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>
<!--            <version>3.0.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>-->
            <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
<!--            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>-->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j-rest</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
            <!--            <type>test-jar</type>
            <scope>test</scope>-->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>opensymphony</groupId>
            <artifactId>sitemesh</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring framework -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
<!--        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.13.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-instrument</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-instrument-tomcat</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
<!--        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
<!--        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc-portlet</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
<!--        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test-mvc</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.3</version>
        </dependency>      
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.1</version>  
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.16</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.springsource.net.sf.cglib</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.coobird</groupId>
            <artifactId>thumbnailator</artifactId>
            <version>0.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>rome</groupId>
            <artifactId>rome</artifactId>
            <version>0.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>10.0.1</version>
        </dependency>            
    </dependencies>
```

Spring configuration file

```
@Configuration
//@EnableScheduling
//@EnableAsync
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.backend"}, excludeFilters = {
    @ComponentScan.Filter(Configuration.class)})
//@ImportResource("classpath:META-INF/spring/spring-data-context.xml")

@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableMBeanExport
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableNeo4jRepositories(basePackages = "com.backend")   
public class MainConfig extends Neo4jConfiguration {

    private static final String DB_PATH = "C:/neo4j/db/neo/graph.db";
  //  private GraphDatabaseFactory graphDbFactory;

    //private GraphDatabaseService databaseService;
    public MainConfig() {
        setBasePackage("com.backend");
    }

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdown")
    public GraphDatabaseService graphDatabaseService() {
        //graphDbFactory = new GraphDatabaseFactory();
        //databaseService = graphDbFactory.newEmbeddedDatabase(DB_PATH);
        return new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase(DB_PATH);
        //  return databaseService;
    }
```

So every time exception with loading db, does not understand repositories....

Who know which version of Spring and Spring data neo4j should  I use?
Also and it is not for use from console, spring service which is use SDN called from web.

Many thanks.

Comment: Spring Data Neo4j automatically pulls in all relevant dependencies. So you don't need to configure anything else.

Answer (score 1):

2 days I tested all versions, finally I have maven pom.xml which is support spring 4.0.7 and spring data neo4j 3.2.1.RELEASE , I created separated project jar, which is included in jsf frontend and Spring service called from jsf bean. here is a pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>neo4j-backend</groupId>
    <artifactId>neo4jsdn</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <!-- General -->
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <!-- Plugin Versions -->
        <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.1</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
        <maven-dependency-plugin.version>2.8</maven-dependency-plugin.version>
        <maven-surefire-plugin.version>2.16</maven-surefire-plugin.version>
        <!-- Dependency versions -->       
        <slf4j.version>1.7.5</slf4j.version>
        <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
        <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>

        <java.source.level>1.7</java.source.level>
        <java.target.level>1.7</java.target.level>
        <neo4j.version>2.1.5</neo4j.version>
        <neo4j.springdata.version>3.2.1.RELEASE</neo4j.springdata.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <aspectj-maven-plugin.version>1.4</aspectj-maven-plugin.version>
        <aspectj.version>1.7.4</aspectj.version>
        <hibernate-jpa-2.0-api.version>1.0.0.Final</hibernate-jpa-2.0-api.version>
        <hibernate-validator.version>4.2.0.Final</hibernate-validator.version>
        <spring.version>4.0.7.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <name>neo4jsdn</name>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-instrument</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-instrument-tomcat</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc-portlet</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- SDN for advanced mapping mode -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>${neo4j.springdata.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate implementation of the JSR-303 Bean Validation Spec API.
       (SDN makes use of the javax.validation:validation-api dependency and
        hibernate provides a concrete implementation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate-validator.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging Related dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- The bulk of our code when sets up and works SDN over is actually in test classes
        so include additional dependencies required to make this work in the tests -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j-kernel</artifactId>
            <version>${neo4j.version}</version>
            <type>test-jar</type>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JPA annotations for spring-aspects compilation which uses @Transactional -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate-jpa-2.0-api.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-6819 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>

            <!-- Advanced mapping uses AspectJ for build-time aspect weaving.
            It is thus necessary to hook the AspectJ Maven plugin into the build process
            as per the config below  -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${aspectj-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
                        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
                        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <outxml>true</outxml>
                    <aspectLibraries>
                        <aspectLibrary>
                            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
                        </aspectLibrary>
                        <aspectLibrary>
                            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j-aspects</artifactId>
                        </aspectLibrary>
                    </aspectLibraries>
                    <source>${java.source.level}</source>
                    <target>${java.target.level}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <url>http://repo.springsource.org/libs-milestone/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>repo.springsource.org.release</id>
            <name>Spring Framework Maven Release Repository</name>
            <url>http://repo.springsource.org/release</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>repo.neo4j.org.releases</id>
            <name>Neo4j Releases Repository</name>
            <url>http://m2.neo4j.org/content/repositories/releases</url>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>spring-libs-milestone-local</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>http://repo.springsource.org/libs-milestone-local</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>


</project>
```

configuration file

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com"}, excludeFilters = {
    @ComponentScan.Filter(Configuration.class)})
@ImportResource("classpath:META-INF/spring/application-context.xml")
@EnableTransactionManagement(mode = AdviceMode.ASPECTJ)
@EnableMBeanExport
@EnableNeo4jRepositories(basePackages = "com")
public class Application extends Neo4jConfiguration {

    public Application() {
        setBasePackage("com");
    }

    @Bean
    public GraphDatabaseService graphDatabaseService() {
        return new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase("C:/neo4j/db/userdata.db");
    }
```

Spring service

```
@Service
@Component
@Transactional
@Qualifier("userService")
public class UserService {

    @Autowired
    private Neo4jTemplate template;
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Transactional
    public User createUserNode(User user) {
        return userRepository.save(user);
    }

    public List<User> getAllUsers() {
        List<User> allList = new ArrayList<User>();
        Iterable<User> users = template.findAll(User.class);
        if (users != null) {
            for (User u : users) {
                allList.add(u);
            }
        }
        return allList;
    }
```